# WatchOS Background fetch

Tags: swift, watchos

I am running into the following issue while developing an WatchOS App.

I have developed a Apple WatchOS Extension which fetches data from an API and displays this. However I want to also have the watch fetch the data in the background. In the Xcode simulator this works perfectly fine. The interval of 5 minutes is working as intended.

However on a physical device this seems to not work at all or at very random times. For example a scheduled refresh for 4:00 PM will trigger at 4:48 PM or even later.

**ExtensionDelegate.swift**

The URLSession is a not existing endpoint for this example purpose.

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    // Perform any final initialization of your application.
    
    // Example scheduling of background task an hour in the future
    WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5.0 * 60.0), userInfo: nil) { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error occured while scheduling background refresh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillResignActive() {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
}

func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        // Use a switch statement to check the task type
        switch task {
        case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
            beginDownloadTask()
            backgroundTask.setTaskCompleted()
        case let snapshotTask as WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Snapshot tasks have a unique completion call, make sure to set your expiration date
            snapshotTask.setTaskCompleted(restoredDefaultState: true, estimatedSnapshotExpiration: Date.distantFuture, userInfo: nil)
        case let connectivityTask as WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the connectivity task once you’re done.
            connectivityTask.setTaskCompleted()
        case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
            urlSessionTask.setTaskCompleted()
        default:
            // make sure to complete unhandled task types
            task.setTaskCompleted()
        }
    }
}

func beginDownloadTask() {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "exampleSessionIdentifier")
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.downloadTask(with: URL(string: "http://www.example.com/data")!)
    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print("Session did complete")
    WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1.0 * 60.0), userInfo: nil) { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            return print("Error occured while scheduling background refresh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        print("Scheduled")
    }
}
}
```